# Number pattern for checkboxes in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, bit

I have a database table which contanis a field name **Province bits** and it adds up the count of the pattern like:

```
AB-1
BC-2
CD-4
DE-8
EF-16.... and so on.
```

Now in the table entry I have a value-13(Province bit), which implies checkboxes against entry AB,CD,DE(adds up to 13)should be checked.

I am not able to get the logic behind the same, how can check only those checkboxes whose sum adds up to the entry in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field is using bit flags.

13 is 1101 binary.

So convert the value to bits and assign one bit to each checkbox.

Comment: kindly provide me the hint how to convert them to bits, this is something I am not getting.

Comment: I am reluctant to give you code.  You learn SO much more when you dig it out your self.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check to see if the value is in the bitwise total.

```
if( interestedInValue & totalValue == interestedInValue) 
{
  // this value is in the total, check the box
}
```

Documentation on & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(v=vs.71).aspx

e.g. 13 = 1 + 4 + 8
13 & 1 == 1 // true
13 & 2 == 2 // false
13 & 4 == 4 // true
13 & 8 == 8 // true
13 & 16 == 16 // false

EDIT: for more clarification

```
ab.Checked = 1 && ProvinceBit == 1  // checkbox AB  
bc.Checked = 2 && ProvinceBit == 2  // checkbox BC  
...
```

Comment: I am not able to get anything in that link, kindly provide me some more detail.

Comment: The link was just provided in case you were looking for more information on the & command. The solution to your particular problem is the use of that operator. I have made an edit to hopefully make it more apparent what you need to do.

Comment: give me an idea for the province bit 13, rest I will do, as I have a long pattern till 4096 and more....

Answer (score 0):

By converting your number to a string, you can convert to an array or just iterate through the string.  A bit brute force, but will give you what you need.

```
var value = 13
string binary = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
//binary = "1101"
```